# Memory limit local and master value difference

Tags: magento2.4, memory-limit

I have a magento 2.4.2 and i have in plesk added memory_limit value at 6124M.
Problem is that when i access my xxx.info.php i see difference in memory limit value.
Local value is 756M and master value is 6124M.
How can i increase my local value to my magento store?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento itself tries to enforce a default 768M limit across-the-board, via rules in **.htaccess** and **pub/.htaccess**: `php_value memory_limit 756M,` and in **.user.ini**: `memory_limit = 756M`

So please update the memory limit in these files .

```
.htaccess
.user.ini

pub/.htaccess
pub/.user.ini
```

Comment: Thanks it was user.ini in pub. Thank you for your reply